# NetSuite splitting 1 field in Saved Search

Tags: netsuite

attempting to write a formula(text) in saved search  to split 3 strings in one field into 3 separate fields. Trying to use SUBSTR and INSTR functions

Example:

Finance & Accounting : Finance : Order Management

Want to see Finance & Accounting in 1 field, Finance in another, etc

Comment: what about `Order Management` ?

Comment: Yes, that string too.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to introduce 3 new fields to the record you are searching on and have those fields populated using script so then you just return the 3 custom fields as columns in your search result? (they could be hidden from the user if you do not want them displaying)

I'll think some more about doing it in formula on a saved search but that was a possible solution that jumped out at me and could be quick to implement.

Also the data returned is populated from where? (NetSuite fieldname would be useful to know) It looks like a hierarchy and I'm wondering if you couldn't go back to the source of that to ascertain the 3 pieces of data you require.

Comment: I was able to figure out the formulas. I will post later. Our NS consultant advised us that the formula in saved search was best course of action